# A way to persist items for Parent items in Core Data using relational data?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, persistent-storage

I have an app which during start, is presented with a Table view controller and a navigation bar with an + button.

So far i have this working well to the point where i can save and delete or edit these objects added to the table view. Each individual Item in this table view is selectable and acts like a folder to get a better picture.

My problem is, how can i work on adding sub data to specific Parent folders?

Sort of works like this graphic representation:

- Folder_one --> - item1,
                - item2
- Folder_two --> - item1
- Folder_three --> - item1,
                  - item2,
                  - item3,
                  - item4

I managed to save the Folders on the Parent view controller and selecting one of them, would navigate to the selected folder's table view controller where the user is yet presented with another + button to add an item which stores data to that particular folder. The user can add as many as he/she wants but i cannot seem to work my way around or figure it out how it would work.

My data model in Core Data is:

Entity name: Folder
Attributes:     'name' of type String
                    ' tabColor' of type Transformable

I have nothing in 'Relationship' nor 'Fetched Properties'

Any help or suggestions from experienced Core Data developers would greatly help overcome this little to big task.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can add an Item entity which has To Many relationship to Folder entity. Folder:name >> Item:title. When segueing to *Selected Folder View Controller* pass current folder i.e.  `Folder *selectedFolder = (Folder*)[self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` You can save the the item using delegate when user segue back to *Parent View Controller*.

Comment: I think your problem statement is not clear. Is `Item1` in folder 1, 2 and 3 the *same* item?